# Find all modal dialogs belonging to a frame

Tags: java, swing, awt

I need to be able to tell if there are any modal dialogs open in my application.  Is there any way to do this?

**Solution**
Alright, so based on the accepted answer, this is what I came up with do accomplish what I needed:

```
Window[] wins : myMainFrame.getOwnedWindows();
for(Window w : wins) {
  if(w instanceof JDialog) {
    JDialog jd = (JDialog)w;
    if(jd.isModal() && jd.isVisible()) {
      // back out of current operation (return null in my case)
      return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: A little more context would be useful to get better help sooner.

Comment: Not sure what other context to give on this one.  I have a Swing application and I need to know if it currently has any modal dialogs open on it.

Comment: I think @dic19 wants to know why this is necessary, because your question may fact be an [XY Problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) where you ask "how do I fix this code problem" when the best solution is to use a different approach entirely.

Comment: In all honesty I was avoiding too much detail on this because I didn't want someone telling me I should do it differently :) (that and it would be a pretty lengthly explanation to satisfy all the people that would tell me to do it differently).  I have already identified this as being the easiest and quickest solution.  Normally I'm all for better ideas than mine, but this is for a very large enterprise application and I don't have access to all of it.

Comment: Well, I've already given you a potential solution to your original question which you can test or ignore as you see fit. But don't be too hasty to avoid listening for other possible approaches. There are some pretty smart folk who answer questions here including some professional coders, and you may be pleasantly surprised that a different way **is** in fact better.

Comment: I totally agree that there are better solutions, but in a large enterprise environment I don't have that luxury this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps calling [Window](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html)'s `getOwnedWindows()` is what you're looking for, and all class that derive from Window will have this method, including JFrame and JDialog.

But I agree that more context would help!

Comment: See my edit on the original question for the full solution that worked for me, thanks!